# Trying to figure out this Android Networking issue

Tags: android, exception, networking

So I'm trying to parse data from a forum website, and this is the code I'm using for the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final List<String> list = formatTopicData(new TopicRetrievalTask().doInBackground(1));
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I also have my ASync task here:

```
 class TopicRetrievalTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<TopicListView.TopicData>> {
 protected List<TopicListView.TopicData> doInBackground(Integer... page) {
    List<TopicListView.TopicData> topics = new ArrayList<TopicListView.TopicData>();
    Document doc;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://<site>/forums/?page=" + page[0])
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .get();

        Elements parsed = doc.select("tr[class=topic]");
        for (Element topic : parsed) {
            TopicListView.TopicData topicData = null;
            topicData.setTitle(topic.select("div").select("a").first().text());
            topicData.setUrl(topic.select("div").select("a").first().attr("href"));
            topicData.setAuthor(topic.select("small").select("a").first().text());
            topics.add(topicData);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return topics;
}
```

For some reason I'm still getting an error saying that I'm doing networking on the main thread, while I'm calling the async task on line 8. Any idea why I would be getting that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are trying to manipulate ui from within the doinbackground () method. That is what causing you troubles. Any type of ui manipulation should be done in the onpostexecute () method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `doInBackground` directly, like this:

```
new TopicRetrievalTask().doInBackground(1)
```

But you should be kicking off the `AsyncTask` like this, and the system will call your doInBackground method on the background thread:

```
new TopicRetrievalTask().execute(1)
```

Note the task is really *async* - you have to wait for it to complete before you can use the results directly, as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to call doInBackground, the documentation will show you that you have to call the execute() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html